# Netbeans: TAB behaviour in brackets

Tags: eclipse, netbeans, tabs, brackets

Is there any way to make Netbeans exit brackets when pressing Tab, just like Eclipse does?

In Eclipse you can see a green line at the position the cursor will move to when pressing Tab, which is after if-conditions, method arguments, etc.

Unfortunately I haven't found a way to teach Netbeans to do the same.

More specifically: For example, when writing an if statement you write "if" and then open the brackets. Both, Netbeans and Eclipse automatically add the closing bracket. So now you are inside the brackets and can define the condition. Now, in Eclipse, pressing Tab while the cursor is inside the brackets will move the cursor behind the brackets. That's what I want to accomplish with Netbeans.

Comment: It's not really clear what you want to accomplish. Could you try to be a little more specific?

Comment: I added a more specific explanation.